# Python 3.6 connect to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.6

I am creating a simple program using python 3.6. I want to connect to the MySQL to use it as my database. Unfortunately most of what i searched is connecting MySQL to lower versions of python. I cannot see about 3.6. Can someone guide me?

Comment: In what way? Do you need help with a specific technical aspect? Do you need literacy training so you can better understand the documentation?

Comment: I have used `mysqlclient` version 1.3.12 with `Python 3.6.2` in windows. See the provided answer of @FELASNIPER for  `mysqlclient`.

Comment: @RobertColumbia nope. I just cannot find any tutorials on using mysql in python. I mean getting started with it. But luckily i saw mysqlclient. I'm now good. Thanks!

Comment: @arsho yeah i saw it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`mysqlclient` officially supports python3.6:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

Also read their documentation:
https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

@Yaypee The following answer helped me:
[[caching sha2 password is not supported mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243506/caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported-mysql][1])

The question posted above is not the same as yours, but the answer tells you that you can use `MySQL.connector` in  python3.6.  I installed it today using `pip3.6 install MySQL-connector-python` on a Windows 10 machine.  The package also supports sha256 cryptography which meant in my case that I could connect using a different user other than root.  The latter of course is unrelated to your question.