# Mysql database not connecting to python

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I am trying to connect python to mysql by this code--
(I am using the mysql.connect library)

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', 
                          password='password',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database='db')
print(cnx)
cnx.close()
```

But it continues to throw the error--

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/ted/main.py", line 5, in <module>
database='db')
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\mysql\connector\__init__.py", 
line 179, in connect
return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\mysql\connector\connection.py", 
line 94, in __init__
self.connect(**kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", 
line 722, in connect
self._open_connection()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\mysql\connector\connection.py", 
line 211, in _open_connection
self._ssl)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\mysql\connector\connection.py", 
 line 141, in _do_auth
auth_plugin=self._auth_plugin)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\mysql\connector\protocol.py", 
line 102, in make_auth
auth_data, ssl_enabled)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\mysql\connector\protocol.py", 
line 58, in _auth_response
auth = get_auth_plugin(auth_plugin)(
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36- 
32\lib\mysql\connector\authentication.py", line 191, in get_auth_plugin
"Authentication plugin '{0}' is not supported".format(plugin_name))
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 
'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have started the mysql sever in workbench and the also checked the status.
Also database named "db" is also there
Also checked if the host is proper.
-->Removed ssl also.

Comment: I think there is some problem with the password encryption

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557234/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your MySQL Server version is 8.x and in that case the default MySQL connector is `caching_sha2_password`. In the other hand your error is maybe because your python client connector does not support this **Authentication Plugin** and you should explicitly change the Authentication Plugin to the old one (`mysql_native_password`).

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='password',
                          host='127.0.0.1', database='db',
                          auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
```