# why geting error while mysql to python connection establishment?

Tags: python, mysql

When I am connecting db in Python I am getting error:

> mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

Code:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="prakash17"
)
print(mydb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered here:
[Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557234/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported)

Solution would be to install mysql-connector-python instead of mysql-connector:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you have misspelled password.
Try this
password = 'prakash17'

If that doesn't work then try 
password = '  '

Also make sure your Xampp is runny apache and mysql. Good luck!