# MySQL error in Python - cannot connect to MySQL server

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I have a question:

My input:

```
import mysql.connector
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    passwd = 'ananthjeahinowiamshowingmypasswordwitchisnotmypassword'
)
print(mydb)
```

And this is the output:

> mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 
> 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

Comment: what is your MySQL version?

Comment: Also, if that's the real password, might consider using `'*****'` for posting on SO. It may not matter in this case, but good practice in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Python MySQL driver:

[Official document](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/8.0.html)

[Similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50557297/7130689)

Just make sure to install the correct connector based on your operating system, MySQL version and the Python version you use:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```