# When I am trying to establish a connection between mysql and Python, the following error rises. How to fix it?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I typed the following code in python, to establish a connection but it is giving me Authentication error--

```
import mysql.connector
mdb=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='SyedAli')

print(mdb)
```

And the error is---

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\mysqlconnection.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       mdb=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='SyedAli')
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\mysql\connector__init__.py",
>   line 179, in connect
>       return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\mysql\connector\connection.py",
>   line 95, in **init**
>       self.connect(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\mysql\connector\abstracts.py",
>   line 716, in connect
>       self._open_connection()   File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\mysql\connector\connection.py",
>   line 210, in _open_connection
>       self._ssl)   File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\mysql\connector\connection.py",
>   line 142, in _do_auth
>       auth_plugin=self._auth_plugin)   File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\mysql\connector\protocol.py",
>   line 102, in make_auth
>       auth_data, ssl_enabled)   File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\mysql\connector\protocol.py",
>   line 58, in _auth_response
>       auth = get_auth_plugin(auth_plugin)(   File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\mysql\connector\authentication.py",
>   line 191, in get_auth_plugin
>       "Authentication plugin '{0}' is not supported".format(plugin_name))
>   mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin
>   'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

Pleae tell me how to fix this error.

Comment: This will be helpful for you to sort out this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557234/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557234/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported)