# Error when using mysql.connector for python to connect MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I was trying to connect MySQL with python. Below's code is what i used but I am getting the error as follows. Do not knowing why getting this error is occurring. Please suggest

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="richajain"
)

print(mydb)
```

```
=============== RESTART: C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\check.py ==============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\check.py", line 7, in <module>
    password="richajain"
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 210, in _open_connection
    self._ssl)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 142, in _do_auth
    auth_plugin=self._auth_plugin)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 102, in make_auth
    auth_data, ssl_enabled)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 58, in _auth_response
    auth = get_auth_plugin(auth_plugin)(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\authentication.py", line 191, in get_auth_plugin
    "Authentication plugin '{0}' is not supported".format(plugin_name))
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

If the above command isn't useful, you should check this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50557297/8904398).

Comment: To clarify: The `mysql-connector`package is known to raise this error, use `mysql-connector-python` instead!