# How to resolve the following "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported" error?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mysql-connector-python

I get the error `sqlalchemy.exc.NotSupportedError: (mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError) Authentication plugin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459623/does-sqlalchemy-support-caching-sha2-password-if-yes-then-how?noredirect=1&lq=1'caching_sha2_password' is not supported`, when I run the following code snippet:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

# Define the MySQL engine using MySQL Connector/Python
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mysql+mysqlconnector://pyuser:Py@pp4Demo@localhost:3306/sqlalchemy', connect_args={'auth_plugin':'mysql_native_password'}, echo=True)

# Define and create the table
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=50))
    fullname = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=50))
    nickname = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='{0}', full name='{1}', nick name='{2}')>".format(
                        self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)

# Create a session
Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

The script having this code snippet was working till a while ago. I recently needed to `import mysql.connector` in another script and performed `pip install mysql-connector-python-rf`. Then, I have started getting this error with this script. I have looked at other threads discussing this error but not able to resolve the error in my case. For e.g., I added `connect_args={'auth_plugin':'mysql_native_password'}` after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459623/does-sqlalchemy-support-caching-sha2-password-if-yes-then-how?noredirect=1&lq=1) but still get the same error.

Comment: I have added one detail. Maybe, this error is more related to SQLAlchemy?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50557234/5320906)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and then figured out it was because i installed the wrong package

pip install mysql-connector-python

then imported as
import mysql.connector

with this command it worked