# Error: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

Tags: python, mysql, terminal, pymysql

Attempting to run a mysql environment through python. Below is the code I tried to run:

[image: Python]

However receive this error message every time:

```
Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

[image: Terminal]

What should I do?

**Expected Output:**
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557234/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).