# how do i use mysql in pycharm

Tags: python, mysql, database, pycharm

trying to create a table on server in pycharm using mysql

```
    import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='root',
    database='Local instance MySQL80',
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)

mycursor = db.cursor()

mycursor.execute('CREATE TABLE Shirt(name VARCHAR(50),price smallint, size smallint, serialnumber int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)')
```

but keep getting the same error

```
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

Comment: U can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557234/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported

Answer (score 0):

You installed a deprecated [mysql-connector](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector/) version. Please use [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/) instead.