# connection database mysql with python 3

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I received a project in which my task is connect the database to python  Finding many Errors when I connect the database mysql with python 3. I installed mysql driver ,`mysql-connector`

```
import mysql.connector as connector
con=connector.connect(host='localhost',
                      port='3306',
                      user='root',
                      password='12345',
                      database='login')
print(con)
```

Error

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\AL Makkah computer\OneDrive\Desktop\mysql python> & "C:/Users/AL Makkah computer/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe" "c:/Users/AL Makkah computer/OneDrive/Desktop/mysql python/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\AL Makkah computer\OneDrive\Desktop\mysql python\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    con=connector.connect(host='localhost',
  File "C:\Users\AL Makkah computer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AL Makkah computer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AL Makkah computer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\AL Makkah computer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 208, in _open_connection
    self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
  File "C:\Users\AL Makkah computer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 137, in _do_auth
    packet = self._protocol.make_auth(
  File "C:\Users\AL Makkah computer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 99, in make_auth
    packet += self._auth_response(client_flags, username, password,
  File "C:\Users\AL Makkah computer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 58, in _auth_response
    auth = get_auth_plugin(auth_plugin)(
  File "C:\Users\AL Makkah computer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\authentication.py", line 190, in get_auth_plugin
    raise errors.NotSupportedError(
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

Comment: And the errors are?

Comment: Are you sure it was developped to use python 3.10 ? maybe try lower version like 3.8, and check also your mysql libs versions

Comment: You need to install `mysql-connector-python`, not `mysql-connector` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557234/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported

Comment: Python 3.10.5 ,      8.0.29 MySQL Community Server

Comment: yes it work when i installed mysql-connector-python.thanks