# No module named 'mysql' has been tossed by python. I can't install the mysql module

Tags: python, mysql

I am running python 3.6.9 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.6.  Code is as follows:

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
#import getpass

usern="***"
# Get the user name from the .my.cnf file
#with open(".my.cnf") as f:
#    config = f.read()
#    print(config.split(" = "))
#    user = config.split(" = ")[1].split(" ")[0]


ipassword = "***"
# Connect to the database
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="battjump",
    user=usern,
    password=ipassword,
    auth_plugin = 'mysql_native_password',
)
```

I'm following the instructions/example on [Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557234/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported)

I'm operating in a venv and have executed the following:

```
pip3 install mysql
Collecting mysql
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/52/8d29c58f6ae448a72fbc612955bd31accb930ca479a7ba7197f4ae4edec2/mysql-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mysqlclient (from mysql)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/5f/eac919b88b9df39bbe4a855f136d58f80d191cfea34a3dcf96bf5d8ace0a/mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error
  Complete output from command /home/jwl/py/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5f45b9xk/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpmu0w2l72pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  mysql_config --version
  ['5.7.42']
  mysql_config --libs
  ['-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '-lmysqlclient', '-lpthread', '-lm', '-lrt', '-latomic', '-lssl', '-lcrypto', '-ldl']
  mysql_config --cflags
  ['-I/usr/include/mysql']
  ext_options:
    library_dirs: ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
    libraries: ['mysqlclient', 'pthread', 'm', 'rt', 'atomic', 'dl']
    extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
    extra_link_args: []
    include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql']
    extra_objects: []
    define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,1,1,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.1.1')]
  /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help
  
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, mysql
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... done
Successfully installed mysql-0.0.3 mysqlclient-2.1.1
```

But compiling the program returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yank.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

The module import.connector.python has been sucessfully installed.  Apparently that replaced the old mysql.connector module which I couldn't install.

Now what?
Thanks,
Jim.

Comment: Chances are the environment where you installed `mysql` and where you are running this program are different.

Comment: And for the record, python programs aren't "compiled".

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221

Comment: You need to install the package `wheel`.