# SQL syntax error when try insert into by python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have the following table in my database:

```
create table tt (
id varchar(20),
hora varchar(20),
preco varchar(20),
qtde varchar(20),
cpa varchar(20),
vda varchar(20),
agressor varchar(20)
);
```

I put them all like varchar (30) because my head was too white with the mistakes they were making.

even with all fields like varchar (30) I am not able to insert into the following 7 values via python

```
19928 12:53:34 4.049,00 5 107 308 Comprador
```

(19928, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':53:34, 4.049,00, 5, 107, 308, Comprador)' at line 1")

my command to insert into is the following:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO tt VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})".format(id_, hora, preco, qtde, cpa, vda, agressor))
conn.commit()
```

could also assist me in what types of variables to use to create the table? (int, varchar (20), float)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a prepared statement here, which would likely also resolve your current errors:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(prepared=True)
sql = """INSERT INTO tt (id, hora, preco, qtde, cpa, vda, agressor)
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
cursor.execute(sql, (id_, hora, preco, qtde, cpa, vda, agressor,))
conn.commit()
```

Using this approach, you let Python/MySQL worry how to properly escape your string data with single quotes.  Also note that it is best practice to *always* explicitly list out the target columns for an insert, which I have done above.

Comment: [Check the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html).

Comment: cursor = conn.cursor(prepared=True)
TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prepared'

Comment: @Leo What is the driver/connector you are using?  Can you check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html) and let us know if it looks familiar to you?

Comment: import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
                  user="root",
                  passwd="****",
                  db="tryd")

Comment: a lot of problems here.  the first: this question, the second: the conector (import mysql.connector), the third: the package (i need to pip install MySQL-connector-python); your and this question help me a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243506/caching-sha2-password-is-not-supported-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO tt VALUES (19928, 12:53:34, 4.049,00, 5, 107, 308, Comprador)
```

which is invalid because of unquoted time and string values, and the comma in one of the numbers. You need to use the prepared statement form:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO tt VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(id_, hora, preco, qtde, cpa, vda, agressor))
conn.commit()
c.close()
```

Note that when you change your column data types, to insert `4.049,00` into MySQL as a number you will need to first swap the `,` and `.` characters.

Comment: Note: OP only has varchar fields .. a problem for another day I suppose.